# For loop issue with Retainsameconnection property Set to true

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm developing a ssis package which utilizes a temp table to store intermediate results. I was having issues using it but then followed the below link and fixed the issue .

```
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/
```

Now i need to execute that set up in multiple instances. I'm using a for loop to run in each server but I've set up Retainsameconnection property to true so it loops through the first server only. Could any one please suggest a solution? If any link or example is provided i would be grateful as  I'm a newbie to ssis.

Answer (score 2):

Best one I've found:
http://sqlstudies.com/2012/10/31/looping-through-multiple-servers-in-ssis/

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm setting Retainsameconnection to true for the connection manager and that's where the issue is. I'm following same steps as the link you provided